# Take date information from ipad

Tags: ios, xcode, nsdate, nsdatecomponents, nsdatepicker

We need to take the actual date from the IPad and save it in a variable. We have searched NSDateComponents and NSDate, but we havent found anything.
For example if today is 25 of october, we would like to have a int with the value of 25 and another with 10 (october).

We will appreciate any help.
Thank you!!

Comment: That's exactly what `NSDate` and `NSDateComponents` lets you do... what troubles are you having?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[What did you try](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Did you at least read the [Date and Time Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003470-SW3) about the subject which explains everything?

The Listing 5 in the documentation gives you pretty much the answer directly

```
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:(NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSInteger day = [comps day];
NSInteger month = [comps month];
```